# Computing limit.

Tags: real-analysis

How do we compute the following limit?

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(x-xe^{-\frac{2}{x}})$$

I was trying to apply L'Hospital rule but is not applicable, is it?

Comment: Right, it is not in the form which l'Hopital's rule applies.  It is possible that some continuous transformation could be used to get this expression into a form where it does apply, but a change of variable might be a simpler way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $y=1/x$. The limit becomes
$$\lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{1-e^{-2y}}{y}.$$
I would now use the power series for $e^{-2y}$.

Comment: Okay, then L'Hospital's rule is applicable then.

Comment: Or you can use L'Hospital here

Comment: L'Hopital is redundant:  The displayed limit is, more or less, the defintion of the (negative of the) derivative of the function $f(y)=e^{-2y}$ at $y=0$.

Comment: Indeed, using L'Hospital here would be circular reasoning. To know the value of this derivative is to know the value of the limit already.

Comment: @ADAM: You can very well use the standard limit $(e^{y} - 1)/y\to 1$ as $y\to 0$ and get the answer as $2$.

Answer (score 1):

The L'Hospital's rule indeed can apply but you have to adjust some terms. Consider the following:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(x-xe^{-\frac{2}{x}})$ 
=$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x(1-e^{-\frac{2}{x}})$
=$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1-e^{-\frac{2}{x}}}{\frac{1}{x}}$.

Now, numerator and denominator are tending to $0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. So, we can apply the L'Hospital's rule.

Therefore , $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1-e^{-\frac{2}{x}}}{\frac{1}{x}}$ = $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{-e^{-\frac{2}{x}}(\frac{2}{x^2})}{\frac{-1}{x^2}}$ = $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}({2e^{-\frac{2}{x}}})$ = $2$.

Answer (score 1):

$x-xe^{-\frac 2x}=x-x(1-\frac 2x+o(\frac 1x))=x-x+2+o(1)=2+o(1)\to 2$ when $x\to\infty$.